# Display a difference line in an ASP.NET chart

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have a chart that is generated from two data sets and it looks like this

[image: Chart]

As you can see the the red line starts slightly earlier and finishes later.  There are also slightly more data points on the red line.

I want to show a third line which displays the difference between the two lines and I cannot determine the best way to do this.

The data comes from a `datatable` which I then convert to a chart.  I have thought about splitting the `datatable` into two tables and then calculating the difference and then charting all three but due to the differing timestamps and number of data points I don't think this will work.

I generate the chart in code and can post the code if needed but I am more looking for a procedure (description/ideas) of how best to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

from my idea:

1. You can  measure the length of time and the offset of time of two
   data sets first.
2. Calculate the smallest interpolated time slice that can be used.
3. Use this slice time and interpolation method to reproduce these two data sets for futher calulation later.
4. Subtracting these two sets of data and generate a third data sets according to the new time slice.
5. Then there are three data sets which have the same time slice.
6. At the final , you are able to show three of them.

ps. the third data sets depend on the short one.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this and instead of deleting I thought I would post my answer as it may help someone in the future as this was very frustrating.

Here are the steps I followed

1. Sort out my data i.e. make sure the start and end points were the same and I had the same number of data points
2. This step was key to me - get the value for each series in the chart.  I did this with the following code.

   ```
   Dim firstSeries As New List(Of Double)

   For Each firstID As DataPoint In Chart1.Series(0).Points

       firstSeries.Add(firstID.YValues.FirstOrDefault)

   Next
   ```
3. I was able to do this for both series and I could therefore work out the difference.
4. I then created a new datatable and added these values into it using the datetime from the first datatable (mentioned in my initial question).
5. I was then able to bind this to the chart using the below

   Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(PONCDataTable.DefaultView, "tagname", "timestamp", "value", "")